# Facebook App and SSL. Why documentation doesn't speak about that?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

This is my first attempt with Facebook App.

I want to create a simple test, a **canvas page** that uses the **PHP SDK** to get some permissions from the users... like the emails and publish_actions.

After something like 2 hours trying to set up my App and following these [OFFICIAL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas/canvas-tutorial) [tutorials](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial) I get that I need SSL certificates to let my canvas app work.

Now I have 2 questions:

1) It's me or the documentation doesn't speak about SSL!? In the previous tutorials I haven't find a word about SSL... I get to know this information here on Stackoverflow.

2) At this point I've a big doubt. Is it true? Do I need SSL to create Facebook Apps?
The `Secure Canvas URL` field has to be filled to ask user for permissions/auth ?

## EDIT

At the moment my App works locally using MAMP PRO. This is enough to learn how to play with Facebook Apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need SSL because for security reasons Facebook forces everything under HTTPS. Additionally you need a real certificate. If you use self signed certificate you will end up having problems with IE.